# How to merge one row with two sql rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This might be a very simple, but I couldnt make it to work.Hope I get some help.

I have a select statement which returns the follow data

```
Id  Name  Phone  msg     File
1    A    null   null     f1
```

another select statement

```
Id     Name   Phone   msg      File
NULL   NULL    123   nothing     f1
NULL   NULL    156   nothing1    f1
```

How do I merge the above as

```
Id     Name   Phone   msg      File
1       A      123   nothing     f1
1       A      156   nothing1    f1
```

I tried using max and group by on File. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What field are you linking to? Some sample data and your Select statements would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm confused, are you just trying to join on the File column and select columns from two tables?

Comment: Could you provide the SELECTs? What database engine we are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

```
Select s1.ID,s1.Name,s2.Phone,s2.msg,s2.File
from s1
Join s2 on s1.file=s2.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

[**SQLFIDDLEExample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef91e/6)

```
SELECT t1.[Id],
       t1.[Name],
       t2.[Phone],
       t2.[msg],
       t2.[File]
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.[File]=t2.[File]
```

Result:

```
| ID | NAME | PHONE |      MSG | FILE |
---------------------------------------
|  1 |    A |   123 |  nothing |   f1 |
|  1 |    A |   156 | nothing1 |   f1 |
```